# How is it possible to fix this error in this circular linked list? (union method)

Tags: java, linked-list

I want to make a method in a circular linked list that gets the union of 2 lists given as an argument but it's not working, I am getting as result many more elements that I have combined in the 2 lists, and I think that my logic is correct, but I don't know what's wrong.
If someone can help me out, I would appreciate it.

This is the method:

```
public CircularLinkedList union(CircularLinkedList a, CircularLinkedList b) {
        Element curA = a.head;
        Element curB = b.head;
        CircularLinkedList c = new CircularLinkedList();
        
        do {
            if(curA.data < curB.data) {
                c.insert(curA.data);
            curA = curA.next;
            }else {
                c.insert(curB.data);
                curB = curB.next;
            }
        }while(curA != a.rear && curB != b.rear);
        
        do {
            c.insert(curA.data);
            curA = curA.next;
        }while(curA != a.rear);
        
        do {
            c.insert(curB.data);
            curB = curB.next;
        }while(curB != b.rear);
        return c;
    }
```

This is the whole class:

```
public class CircularLinkedList {
    
class Element{
        
        int data;     // int type used as example
        Element next; // reference of the successor
        
        Element(int value) {
            this.data = value;
            this.next = this;
        }
        
    }

    private Element head = null;
    private Element rear = null;

    public CircularLinkedList() {
        this.head = this.rear = null;
    }
    
    
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return head == null;
    }
    
    
    public boolean findValue(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        while(cur != null) {
            if (cur.data == value)
                return true;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    public int countValue(int value) {
        int c = 0; // counter
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        if(cur == null) 
            return 0;
        
        do {
            if(cur.data == value) 
                c++;
            cur = cur.next;
            
        }while (cur != this.head);
            
        return c;
    }
    
    
    public boolean isInList(int value) {
        if(this.head == null)
            return false;
        
        Element cur = this.head;
        while(cur != this.rear) {
            if(cur.data == value)
                return true;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str = "";
        Element cur = this.head;
        
            if(cur == null) 
                return "The list is empty";
        
            do {
                str += cur.data + " | ";
                cur = cur.next;
            
            }while (cur != this.head);
            
        return str;
        }
    
    
    
    public void insert(int value) {
        Element tmp = new Element (value);
//      Element cur = this.head;
//      Element prev = null;
        
        //special case: empty list
        if(this.head == null) {
            tmp.next = tmp;
            this.head = tmp;
            this.rear = tmp;
            
        }else { // general case
//          while (cur != rear && cur.data < value) { //ascending
//               prev = cur;
//               cur = cur.next;
//           }
//           
//           tmp.next = cur;
//           cur.next = tmp;
//      }  
//  }
            tmp.next = this.head;
            this.rear.next = tmp; 
            this.rear = tmp;
        }
            
    }
    
    
    public void deleteAtHead() {
        if(this.head == null) 
            return;
        
        Element cur = this.head;    
        while(cur.next != this.head) {            
             cur = cur.next;
            }
            cur.next = cur.next.next;       
            this.head = this.head.next;                
            return ;    
    }
    
    
    public void deleteAtRear() {
        if(this.head == null)
            return;
        
        Element cur = this.head;
//      Element prev = null;
        while(cur.next != this.rear) {
//          prev = cur;
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        cur.next = cur.next.next;
        this.rear = cur;
        
    }
    
        
    public boolean delete(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        
        if(this.head.data == value) {                  //if the node to be deleted is head node
        
            while(cur.next != this.head) {         //iterate till the last node i.e. the node which is pointing to head         
                cur = cur.next;
            }
            cur.next = cur.next.next;       // update current node pointer to next node of head
            this.head = this.head.next;                //update head node
            return true;
        }
        else {                              // if node to be deleted is other than head node
        
            Element prev = cur;               // track previous node from current (node)
            while(cur.data != value) {       // find the node           
                prev = cur;
                cur = cur.next;
            }
            prev.next = cur.next; //updating next field of previous node to next of current node.current node deleted
            return true;
        }
    }
    
    
    
    public void deleteEven() {
//      if(this.head == null)
//          return;
//      
//      //case of deleting the head
//      if(this.head.data % 2 == 0) {
//          this.head.next = this.head;
//          this.rear.next = this.head;
//      if(this.head == null) 
//          this.rear = null;
//      }
//      
//      Element cur = this.head;
//      Element prev = cur;
//      while(cur != this.head) {
//          prev = cur;
//          cur = cur.next;
//      }
//      prev.next = cur.next;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return;
        Element cur = this.head;
        while(cur.next != this.head) {
            if(cur.data % 2 == 0)
                this.delete(cur.data);
            cur = cur.next;
        }
    }
    
    
    public void deleteLastOccurence(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        Element prev = null;
        Element tmp = null;
        
        if(this.head == null)
            return;
        
        if(this.rear.data == value) {
            this.head = null;
            return;
        }
        
//      while(cur != this.rear) {
            while(cur.next != this.head && cur.next.data != value) {
                prev = cur;
                tmp = cur.next;
//              cur = cur.next;
            }
//          cur = cur.next;
//      }
        prev.next = tmp.next;
    }
    
    
    public void deleteAllOccurrences(int value) {
        Element cur = this.head;
        Element next = null;

        if (cur.data == value) {
            cur = cur.next;
            this.head = cur;
        }

        do {
            next = cur.next;
            if (next.data == value) {
                cur.next = next.next;
            }
            cur = next;

        } while (cur != this.head);
    }
    
    
    public static CircularLinkedList union(CircularLinkedList a, CircularLinkedList b) {
        Element curA = a.head;
        Element curB = b.head;
        CircularLinkedList c = new CircularLinkedList();
        
        do {
            if(curA.data < curB.data) {
                c.insert(curA.data);
            curA = curA.next;
            }else {
                c.insert(curB.data);
                curB = curB.next;
            }
        }while(curA != a.rear && curB != b.rear);
        
        do {
            c.insert(curA.data);
            curA = curA.next;
        }while(curA != a.rear);
        
        do {
            c.insert(curB.data);
            curB = curB.next;
        }while(curB != b.rear);
        return c;
    }
    
    
    public CircularLinkedList inter(CircularLinkedList a, CircularLinkedList b) {
        Element curA = a.head;
        CircularLinkedList c = new CircularLinkedList();
        
        if(a.head == null || b.head == null)
            return c;
        
        while(curA != a.rear) {
            if(b.isInList(curA.data))
                c.insert(curA.data);
            curA = curA.next;
        }
        return c;
    }
    
    
    public boolean isEqualTo(CircularLinkedList a) {  //same content in same order
        Element cur = this.head;
        Element curA = a.head;
        
        while(cur != this.rear && curA != a.rear) {
            if(cur.data != curA.data) {
                return false;
            }
            cur = cur.next;
            curA = curA.next;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    
    public int countOddNbrs() {
        if(this.head == null)
            return 0;
        
        int c = 0;
        Element cur = this.head;
        do {
            if(cur.data % 2 != 0)
                c++;
            cur = cur.next;
        }while(cur != this.head);
        return c;
    }

    
    public int findLastOccurence(int value) {
        if(this.head == null)
            return -1;
        
        if(!isInList(value))
            return -1;
        
        if(this.head.data == this.rear.data)
            this.head =null;
        
        Element cur = this.head;
        Element prev = null;
        Element tmp = null;
        int c = 0;
        while(cur != this.rear) {
            if(cur.next != this.head && cur.next.data == value) {
                prev = cur;
                tmp = cur.next;
                c++;
            }
            cur = cur.next;
        }
        return c;
    }
    
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CircularLinkedList list = new CircularLinkedList();
        CircularLinkedList list1 = new CircularLinkedList();
        CircularLinkedList list2 = new CircularLinkedList();
        
        list.insert(8);
        list.insert(2);
        list.insert(4);
        list.insert(3);
        list.insert(10);
        list.insert(5);
        list.insert(8);
        list.insert(4);     
        System.out.println(list);
        
//      list2.insert(8);
//      list2.insert(2);
//      list2.insert(4);
//      list2.insert(3);
//      list2.insert(10);
//      list2.insert(5);
//      list2.insert(8);
//      list2.insert(4);        
//      System.out.println(list);
        
        list1.insert(5);
        list1.insert(1);
        list1.insert(3);
        list1.insert(7);
        list1.insert(0);
        list1.insert(6);
        list1.insert(-4);
        list1.insert(1);        
        System.out.println(list1);
        
//      System.out.println(list.findValue(2)); // working
        
//      list.delete(8);  // working
//      System.out.println(list);
                
//      System.out.println(list.countOddNbrs());  //working
        
//      list.deleteEven();  //  working
//      System.out.println(list);
        
//      list.deleteAtHead();  //  working
//      System.out.println(list);
        
//      list.deleteAtRear();  //   working
//      System.out.println(list);
        
//      list.deleteLastOccurence(4);  //not working
//      System.out.println(list);
        
//      list.deleteAllOccurrences(4);  // working
//      System.out.println(list);
                 
//      System.out.println(union(list, list1));  //not working
                
//      System.out.println(list2.inter(list, list1));  //working
        
//      System.out.println(list.isEqualTo(list1));  // working

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you use a do while loop the seconden and thrid do while loop can cause the problem, when in the first all element a inserted the the new list. I would do it like this:

```
   public static CircularLinkedList union(CircularLinkedList a, CircularLinkedList b) {
    Element curA = a.head;
    Element curB = b.head;
    CircularLinkedList c = new CircularLinkedList();

    while (!(curA == a.rear && curB == b.rear)) {
        if (curA == a.rear) {
            c.insert(curB.data);
            curB = curB.next;
        } else if (curB == b.rear) {
            c.insert(curA.data);
            curA = curA.next;
        } else if (curA.data < curB.data) {
            c.insert(curA.data);
            curA = curA.next;
        } else {
            c.insert(curB.data);
            curB = curB.next;
        }
    }
    return c;
}
```

When you start to gernify you class merge sort could be very use full.
Also I would check on duplicates.

Comment: If I want to update my ```insert``` method so it sort the elements in an ascending order, how should I do it?

Comment: Start at the head compare whether the element to insert is smaller or greater
- if smaller insert as new head 
- if greater go to the next element
- if equal and you don´t wont duplicates return;

Comment: I wrote the insert method but it's looping infinitely and I'm not getting any results. How can I contact you to check my work.

Comment: Do you tried to debug?
Is the rear element null?

Comment: I didn't learn how to debug, and no the rear is not null.

Comment: Did you change your insert method?
The problem is that you create an recursion when you frist insert an element becuase is links to itself and the head does not change.
You have to dicide whether you want to add the element at the front or end.
Something like:
 public void addFirst(E element) {
        head.next = new Node<>(element, head.next);
    }
or
 public void addLast(E element) {
        Node<E> tmp = head;
        while (tmp.next != null)
            tmp = tmp.next;
        tmp.next = new Node<>(element, null);
    }
If you want your list sorted you need to add compares.

Comment: I changed it all, how can I show it to you? Do I edit my post and put it in it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232577/discussion-between-p-em-and-marlon).